# Find all log events of type A that occur between types B and C

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to find a nice way to find all events of type A that occur at a time between event types B and C.

Also, events B and C must share a process_id.

Each process_id group will have one B event and one C event.

**Table structure looks like this:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eventlog` (  
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `process_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
  `event` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `data` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
)
```

**My attempt looked like this:**

```
SELECT q3.time, q3.event, q3.process_id, q3.data   
FROM `eventlog` as q1, `eventlog` as q2, `eventlog` as q3 
WHERE q1.process_id=q2.process_id AND q1.process_id=q3.process_id 
AND q1.event='EVENTB' AND q2.event='EVENTC' AND q3.event='EVENTA'  
AND q3.time BETWEEN q1.time AND q2.time
```

When I run this, it hangs. Any thoughts on a more efficient, or fixed way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: B-C-A-B-C in this case A is between a B and a C but is it acceptable?

Comment: Each process_id will only have one B event, and one C event. So, this shouldn't be a problem. I will clarify in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a group by to get start and end times for each process_id. This can then be used to join back to the eventlog table and select the required records.

```
SELECT * FROM eventlog e

JOIN (
    SELECT 
        process_id, 
        MIN(CASE event WHEN 'EVENTB' THEN time END) start_time,
        MAX(CASE event WHEN 'EVENTC' THEN time END) end_time
    FROM eventlog
    GROUP BY process_id
) t
    ON e.time BETWEEN t.start_time AND t.end_time

WHERE
    e.event = 'EVENTA'
```